# How to prevent Xubuntu from resetting monitor resolution and refresh rate when turning monitor back on an off?

Tags: xubuntu, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

*Edit: To clarify, this only happens on Xubuntu 18.04. It does not happen on Windows or the BIOS/UEFI prompt.*

*Edit: Expanded my work around a bit.*

*Edit: AMD hasn't released proprietary drivers yet for 18.04. I tried but they're extremely unstable.*

So, when I turn my monitor off, then back on, the resfresh rate drops to 59hz and my resolution goes to 1366×768. My monitor is an ASUS 144hz 1080p monitor, but after I do this, it will stay stuck there and I can no longer set the monitor to its optimal resolution and refresh rate.

I'm really not sure why this happens. I've listed my specs below. I'll try to figure out what version I'm using of the open source drivers.

---

**Expected:**

Turning monitor on and off and then back on should use correct display resolution and refresh rate.

**Result:**

Turning off monitor, then turning it back on changes display resolution and refresh rate, along with removing the option to change to anything higher than 1376x768 and 59hz.

**Work Around:**

Unplug monitor from power, then plug back in.

**System Specs:**

- Xubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Sapphire Radeon RX 580 Pulse 8GB
- R7 2700x
- Asus Crosshair VII Hero X470
- Open-source AMD Radeon driver
- Asus - VG278Q 27.0" 1920x1080 144Hz Monitor
- Displayport

**Driver Information:**

```
 *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
   version: e7
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:70 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe900000-fe93ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Kernal Information:**

```
Linux xubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It does not happen with Windows or the BIOS/UEFI prompt.

Comment: What happens with the proprietary drivers?

Comment: AMD hasn't released proprietary drivers yet for 18.04. I tried but they're extremely unstable.